# Need help creating maxHeap function

Tags: c, tree, binary, max, heap

```css
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct listNode {
  int id;
  struct listNode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct treeNode {

  char *word;
  char *key;
  int freq;
  ListNode *head;
  struct treeNode *left;
  struct treeNode *right;
} TreeNode;


TreeNode *insertItem(TreeNode *root, char *gword);
void printTreeInorder(TreeNode *v);
void searchforexist(TreeNode *root, char *key);
int searchItem(TreeNode *root, char *word);
void Heap(TreeNode *arr[],TreeNode *root, int i);
void maxheap(TreeNode *arr[],int k);
void freeNodes(TreeNode *root);

#define MAX 25
int main() {
  char in[MAX];

  char word[MAX];
  TreeNode *root = NULL;
  int comp;
  int f=0;
  int t=0;
  FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

  memset(word, 0, MAX);
  if (fp != NULL) {
   
    while (fscanf(fp, "%24s \n", word) != EOF) {
      
      root = insertItem(root, word);//insert items
      t++;
      if (strcmp(word, "eof") == 0) break;
    }

    fclose(fp);
  }
  
  // User inputs word 
   printf("Give word");
   printf("\n");
   scanf("%s",in);
   comp=strcmp(in,"#");
  
  while(comp!=0)
  {
      printf("Give word");
     printf("\n");
     scanf("%s",in);
     comp=strcmp(in,"#");
     if(comp==1)
       break;
    
     f=searchItem(root,in);
     printf("%d",f);
     f=0;
     printf("\n");
  }
    TreeNode *arr[t];
    Heap(arr,root,t);// HEAPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP

  printTreeInorder(root);
  printf("\n");

  freeNodes(root);
  return 0;
}

TreeNode *insertItem(TreeNode *root, char *gword) {
  TreeNode *v = root;
  TreeNode *pv = NULL;
  
  while (v != NULL) {
   
    pv = v;
    int comp = strcmp(gword, v->word);
    
    if (comp < 0) {
       
      v = v->left;
    } else if (comp > 0) {
      v = v->right;
     
    } else {
      char *word = v->word;
      searchforexist(root,v->word);
     
      return root;
    }
  }
 
 
  TreeNode *tmp = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
 
 
  tmp->word = strdup(gword);
  
  tmp->left = tmp->right = NULL;
  tmp->freq = 1;

  if (root != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(gword, pv->word) < 0) {
      pv->left = tmp;
    } else {
      pv->right = tmp;
    }
  } else
    root = tmp;


  return root;
}

void searchforexist(TreeNode *root, char *word) {
  if(root == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  int comp = strcmp(word, root->word);

  if(comp == 0) {
    root->freq++;
  } else {
    searchforexist(comp < 0 ? root->left : root->right , word);
  }

}



int searchItem(TreeNode *root, char *word)
{
 if(root == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

  int comp = strcmp(word, root->word);

  if(comp == 0) {
    return root->freq;
  } else {
    searchItem(comp < 0 ? root->left : root->right , word);
  }

}

void Heap(TreeNode *arr[],TreeNode *root, int i)
{
int  k=0;
  while(k<i)
  {
  if(root==NULL){
    maxheap(arr,k);
  }
  
   arr[k]=root;
   k++;
   if (k=i){
      maxheap(arr,k);
      break;
   }
   
   Heap(arr,root->left,k);
   Heap(arr,root->right,k);
  }
}

void maxheap(TreeNode *arr[],int k)
{
   int i;
    int j;
   for (i = 0; i < k; i++)   
     {                 
      for (j = 0; j < k; j++)       
       {
           if(arr[i]->freq>arr[j]->freq)
             {
                TreeNode *tmp = arr[i];         
  arr[i] = arr[j];           
  arr[j] = tmp;        
      }
      }
     }
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)   
     {    
       printf("%s %d",arr[i]->word,arr[i]->freq);
    }
}

void printTreeInorder(TreeNode *v) 
{
    if (v==NULL) return;

    printf("(");
    printTreeInorder(v->left);
    printf(")");

    printf(" %.4s ", v->word);

    printf("(");
    printTreeInorder(v->right);
    printf(")");
}

void freeNodes(TreeNode *root) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  freeNodes(root->left);
  freeNodes(root->right);

  if(root->word != NULL) free(root->word);
  if(root->key != NULL) free(root->key);
  free(root);
  return;
}
```

This program reads a file and puts all strings to a binary search tree. Repeating words are not added but the frequency counter increases (searchforexist). Then the user types a word and the program displays the frequency of the word typed. 
The above works fine using any input file.

However im having trouble with the next steps of the assignment:

After that the hole tree is suppose to be copied in a maxheap based on the frequency of each word. The heap must be created using array with size equal to the elements of a tree. Every cell of said array must contain a pointer that points to a node in the binary search tree so we can still access the word inside and its frequency.

The user then inputs an int number and the programm prints all words that have frequency less that the number inputed by the user.

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct listNode {
  int id;
  struct listNode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct treeNode {

  char *word;
  char *key;
  int freq;
  ListNode *head;
  struct treeNode *left;
  struct treeNode *right;
} TreeNode;


TreeNode *insertItem(TreeNode *root, char *gword);
void printTreeInorder(TreeNode *v);
void searchforexist(TreeNode *root, char *key);
int searchItem(TreeNode *root, char *word);
void freeNodes(TreeNode *root);

#define MAX 25
int main() {
  char in[MAX];

  char word[MAX];
  TreeNode *root = NULL;
  int comp;
  int f=0;

  FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

  memset(word, 0, MAX);
  if (fp != NULL) {

    while (fscanf(fp, "%24s \n", word) != EOF) {

      root = insertItem(root, word);//insert items

      if (strcmp(word, "eof") == 0) break;
    }

    fclose(fp);
  }

  // User inputs word 
   printf("Give word");
   printf("\n");
   scanf("%s",in);
   comp=strcmp(in,"#");

  while(comp!=0)
  {
      printf("Give word");
     printf("\n");
     scanf("%s",in);
     comp=strcmp(in,"#");
     if(comp==1)
       break;

     f=searchItem(root,in);
     printf("%d",f);
     f=0;
     printf("\n");
  }

   //heapcreating here 


  printTreeInorder(root);
  printf("\n");

  freeNodes(root);
  return 0;
}

TreeNode *insertItem(TreeNode *root, char *gword) {
  TreeNode *v = root;
  TreeNode *pv = NULL;

  while (v != NULL) {

    pv = v;
    int comp = strcmp(gword, v->word);

    if (comp < 0) {

      v = v->left;
    } else if (comp > 0) {
      v = v->right;

    } else {
      char *word = v->word;
      searchforexist(root,v->word);

      return root;
    }
  }


  TreeNode *tmp = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));


  tmp->word = strdup(gword);

  tmp->left = tmp->right = NULL;
  tmp->freq = 1;

  if (root != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(gword, pv->word) < 0) {
      pv->left = tmp;
    } else {
      pv->right = tmp;
    }
  } else
    root = tmp;


  return root;
}

void searchforexist(TreeNode *root, char *word) {
  if(root == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  int comp = strcmp(word, root->word);

  if(comp == 0) {
    root->freq++;
  } else {
    searchforexist(comp < 0 ? root->left : root->right , word);
  }

}



int searchItem(TreeNode *root, char *word)
{
 if(root == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

  int comp = strcmp(word, root->word);

  if(comp == 0) {
    return root->freq;
  } else {
    searchItem(comp < 0 ? root->left : root->right , word);
  }

}


void printTreeInorder(TreeNode *v) 
{
    if (v==NULL) return;

    printf("(");
    printTreeInorder(v->left);
    printf(")");

    printf(" %.4s ", v->word);

    printf("(");
    printTreeInorder(v->right);
    printf(")");
}

void freeNodes(TreeNode *root) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  freeNodes(root->left);
  freeNodes(root->right);

  if(root->word != NULL) free(root->word);
  if(root->key != NULL) free(root->key);
  free(root);
  return;
}
```

Comment: 1) Curious.  Good use of `"%24s` in reading the file, but no width in `scanf("%s",in);` for user input.  Suggest `scanf("%24s",in);`  2) Post some sample input your are using that causes the trouble.  3) Explain the trouble  in more detail.

Comment: You say you're having trouble with the next part of the assignment, but you don't say what the trouble is. You didn't ask a question. Please edit your post and *ask a specific question.*

Answer (score 2):

I and many of us make simple mistakes.  Use the automated tools you have to increase your coding efficiency.

Save time, enable all compiler warnings - or use a better compiler.

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

`searchItem()` needs to return a value.

```
int searchItem(TreeNode *root, char *word) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

  int comp = strcmp(word, root->word);

  if (comp == 0) {
    return root->freq;
  } else {

    // searchItem(comp < 0 ? root->left : root->right, word);
    return searchItem(comp < 0 ? root->left : root->right, word);
  }
}
```

Other problems may exist.